# Set paper size in Jasper to be recognized in Excel

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have an `Excel` report that I generate with `Jasper 3.7.5`.
If I preview the file the last column of the report is not shown. [image]

If I change the paper size in `Page Setup` from `Letter`  to `A4` then the last column is shown.
[image]

When I try to print it, in the `Print` dialog the first option for paper size is `Letter`. *Is it possible to set the paper size from Jasper in such a way that the `Excel` would recognize that it is `A4` and would set the `Paper Size` to `A4`? Or is this only possible in Excel and not in Jasper?* It would be nice to have the `Paper Size` selected to `A4` both in the `Print` dialog and in the preview.

The report width and height (that are set up in the `jrxml` inside the `jasperReport` tag) are calculated like this:

```
// A4 size is 210 mm X 297 mm
int quality = 236; // 236 dpmm = 600 dpi
int width = 210 * quality / 98;
int height = 297 * quality / 98;
```

I do not know why the formula needs to be divided with 98. However I have noticed that setting the value above 100 has no visible effects on the report.

**UPDATE:**
The report is in landscape mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not solve this in Jasper. I have solved it by manipulating the report after it is generated and before it is sent back to browser using the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) API:

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
sheet.getPrintSetup().setPaperSize(PrintSetup.A4_PAPERSIZE);
```

Comment: If somebody knows a better solution, please share it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the widht and height of the report to the fixed size, for A4 format it should be: w=595 and h=842 in portrait mode.

When using your calculations, I get: w=505.7 and h=715.22

Comment: I do not know where did you get 595 and 842 from but I have set the 98 to 83.29 to get your values and strange enough (even though the report is wider than before) the Excel preview shows less columns than before. From Column15 on (inclusive) I do not see anything from the report.